# Can get passed heap space error in Netbeans

Tags: java

I'm working on a code that takes user input for a text file and then searches line by line through the text file for palindromes. It then writes the lines that are palindromes to a separate text file. I am getting a heap space error and have tried putting `-Xmx512m` in the vm options section of NetBeans to fix this.
The error is being caused by three sections of my code

```
public void StringToStack(String inStr){
        for(int i = 0; i < inStr.length() - 1; i++){
            Character a = inStr.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isLetter(a)){
                myCharacters.push(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public CharStack Reverse(){
        if(myCharacters.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is empty");
            return null;
        }
        else{
            
            String copy = myCharacters.toString();
            CharStack stack = new CharStack();
            while(copy.isEmpty()==false){
                stack.StringToStack(copy);
            }
            return stack;
        }    
    }
```

```
           CharStack rev  = ch.Reverse();
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete stack trace of the exception, and a minimal, runnable example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Look at `while(copy.isEmpty()==false){ stack.StringToStack(copy); }`. If `copy.isEmpty()` is `false` to start with, when will it become `true`?

Comment: @tgdavies The second comment actually helped a lot. I changed the while to an if statement and now the program works great. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries. To debug problems like this: reproduce them as small an input as possible, then step through your program in the debugger (or set a breakpoint where you think the problem is). Learning to use the debugger is a vital development skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was as tgDavies state with the while statement. Changing that to an if rather than a while cleared my heap issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).